# How to display data store in the database on a blade.php file

Tags: php, laravel

I try retrieving data from a single auth user  in my **index.blade.php** file

```
<h3 class="profile-username text-center">{{$user ?? ''->lastname}}</h3>
```

using my **ProfileController**

```
public function index($user){
        $user_id = auth()->user()->id;
        $user = User::findOrFail($user_id);
        return view('profiles.index')->with('users',$user);
    }
```

and the user data is in my **users table**

```
public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id');
            $table->string('accno')->unique();
            $table->string('acc_type');
            $table->string('firstname');
            $table->string('middlename');
            $table->string('lastname');
            $table->string('address');
            $table->string('email')->unique();
            $table->timestamp('email_verified_at')->nullable();
            $table->string('phoneno')->unique();
            $table->string('sex');
            $table->string('martial_status');
            $table->string('password');
            $table->rememberToken();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
```

and **route**

```
Route::get('/profile/{user}', 'ProfilesController@index')->name('profiles.show');
```

I keep getting this Laravel error:

> Trying to get property 'lastname' of non-object (View: C:\Users\user pc\Desktop\dkn\resources\views\profiles\index.blade.php).

Comment: What is this ? `{{$user ?? ''->lastname}}` .. you mean `$user->lastname` ?

Comment: I'm echoing out the php in my index.blade.php file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since in the controller you used `findOrFail()`, when you reach the blade, you 100% have a instance of `User` from the databse. So you dont need to check for it there.

```html
<h3 class="profile-username text-center">{{$user->lastname}}</h3>
```

If you want to check for it, do it like this

```html
<h3 class="profile-username text-center">{{$user->lastname ?? ''}}</h3>
```

or

```html
<h3 class="profile-username text-center">{{$user ? $user->lastname : ''}}</h3>
```

BTW, you dont need to recover the user from the database since it's already in the laravel auth

```php
public function index($user){
    $user = auth()->user();
    return view('profiles.index')->with('users',$user);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This

```
{{$user ?? ''->lastname}}
```

must be

```
{{ $user->lastname ?? '' }}
```

You are sending a user object from the controller. If you need to access an object property you have to use the syntax object->property.

Comment: that will trigger a compilation error. change the `??` to a single `?`. `?` => if else. `??` => if-isset - return